# Custom top-menu bar in various HTML

Tags: html, templates, menubar

Is there a way to create a top-menu bar template what can be applied in further HTML webpages I create in the future, so when I make a change to the menu bar it applies automatically to all webpages?

**Please no iFrame**

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you use for generating and serving html?

Comment: Servlets, but It dosen´t really matter webpage are already created I just dragged the file, edit it and send it as response

Comment: If it's java servlets then you can look at jsp. It has possibility to include common parts of html.

`<%@ include file="header.jsp" %> `